# Not able to delete an Azure share using AZ CLNot able to delete an Azure share using AZ CLI or REST APII or REST API

Tags: azure, rest, azure-storage

I'm not able to delete a share, having the following issues:

```
az storage share delete --name share1 --account-key $key --account-name $sa_name --delete-snapshots include
```

Error:

> Unable to delete share because one or more share snapshots have active
> leases. Release the share snapshot leases or delete the share with the
> include-leased parameter for x-ms-delete-snapshots.

When using REST API to breat a lease:

```
body='
{
  "action": "Break",
  "leaseid": "LEASE_ID",
  "breakPeriod": null,
  "leaseDuration": null,
  "proposedLeaseId": null
}'
headers='
{
  "x-ms-lease-id": "LEASE_ID",
  "x-ms-lease-action": "break",
  "x-ms-date": "2023-10-22T23:40:54.0000000Z"
}'
uri="https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{SubID}/resourceGroups/{RG_NAME}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{SA_NAME}/fileServices/default/shares/{SHARE_NAME}/lease?>
az rest --method post --body "$body" --headers "$headers" --uri "$uri"
```

Error:

> Conflict({"error":{"code":"LeaseNotPresentWithLeaseOperation","message":"`LeaseNotPresentWithLeaseOperation`There
> is currently no lease on the file
> share.\nRequestId:003d9a62-901a-00a8-0a12-0609c8000000\nTime:2023-10-24T00:39:16.3735661Z"}})

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Lease may not be on main share but on one of its snapshots. You will have to break the lease on the snapshot, not the primary share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unable to delete share because one or more share snapshots have active leases. Release the share snapshot leases or delete the share with theinclude-leased parameter for x-ms-delete-snapshots.

The error shows in your **`File-share`** has some active snapshots or lease present in some files so that cannot be deleted.

I agree with Daredevil's comment which **`Lease`** may be on a snapshot instead of the main share.

In my environment, I have a file with a lease like the below:

**Portal:**

[image]

You can use the below command to break the lease in Azure file share.

**Command:**

```
$headers = @{
    "x-ms-lease-action"= "break"
}

$uri = "https://<storage account name>.file.core.windows.net/<sharename>/<path upto filename>?comp=lease&sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2023-10-24T12:16:53Z&st=2023-10-24T04:16:53Z&spr=https&sig=xxx" #fileurl+sastoken

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Headers $headers -Uri $uri
```

The above command will break the lease for the file.

**Output:**

[image]

Now you can use the same command to delete the share it will delete now.

**Reference:**

[Lease File (FileREST API) - Azure Files | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-file)